# Style UIPageControl when using AlzheimerPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

There's a well documented bug in iOS where the UIPageViewController with transitionStyle: .Scroll does not properly track the index due to internal caching (on swipe, it'll skip index == 1). This person kindly solved the problem with the following gist:  https://gist.github.com/paul-delange/5582394.

Question: how do you style UIPageControl when using AlzheimerPageViewController rather than UIPageViewController? The following (swift) code works for a normal UIPageViewController, if you put it in AppDelegate application/didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function, but does not apply with the AlzheimerPageViewController. My goal is to style the PageControl (aka the dots) gray, as they are on a white background.

```
    let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xdddddd)
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x666666)
    pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

This is how i instantiate the AlzheimerPageViewController in viewDidLoad():

```
    var pageViewController = AlzheimerPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as CreditCardContentView
    var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)
    // Draw and set up the page view controller
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as! [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.width, 235)
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
```

To be clear, the AlzheimerPageViewController works great and solves the index/caching bug. Just trying to figure out the UIPageControl.